# Cannot use a created function in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is that I cannot use the function I have created. You can see the codes below. I am getting a "not a function error".

```
var alteropacity = function () {                 //creating function
    if ($(this).css('opacity') < '0.90') {
        $(this).css('opacity', '1.00');
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('opacity', '0.20');
    }
    return $(this);
};
$("#image").on("click", function () {           //using it
    $(this).alteropacity(); 
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make a function available as a jQuery method, you have to add a property to `$.fn`:

```
$.fn.alteropacity = alteropacity;
```

Add that right after the function declaration (outside the event handler).

Now, while your code will work, if you *really* want to make a jQuery method it should follow convention (if that's meaningful for the function's purpose). In this case, it just means iterating:

```
var alteropacity = function () {
    return this.each(function() {
      if ($(this).css('opacity') < '0.90') {
        $(this).css('opacity', '1.00');
      }
      else {
        $(this).css('opacity', '0.20');
      }
    });
};
```

That way the method will work if you were to do something like

```
$(".common-class").alteropacity();
```

That is, if you were to use the function to affect many elements. Also note that in a jQuery method `this` refers to the jQuery object for which the method is being invoked. It doesn't hurt to wrap it again (`$(this)`) but you don't have to. Inside the `.each()` iteration, however, you're back in familiar territory so `this` inside that callback will refer to the elements involved.

Comment: Actually I am selecting the elements one by one and do not need any loop to change the css property. Additionally I have got another error at foreach line including a deeper library error regarding usage.I am trying to make a click event triggered to change a css property.That is all .

Comment: @SophisticatedUndoing yes I understand that. The loop won't hurt anything however (it will still work if you've got just one element), and the point was more to explain in general how jQuery methods work. You don't need to add the loop if you don't want it :)

Comment: I have forgetten to thank you :D the information you provide will be useful. I am trying to reveal a complete solution so that I can post it in here :) Take care.

Comment: Actually I do not have to share at here I just remove the this.each part :)